# How to generate more Cosmos DB connection strings

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We have several app service APIs which will read from same Cosmos DB. We want each API use different connection string for security reason. But from Azure portal, seems we can only have 2 master connection strings and 2 read-only connection strings. 
Can I generate more read-only connection strings?

Answer (score 1):

That is not directly supported, but there are other ways to achieve what you're looking for.

Essentially, you are now using the 'Master Keys' approach to define your connection string. You are building it by specifying the account and one of the 2 master keys to access your data.

The only other approach available is the 'Resource Token' approach. In this architecture you'd have a middleware tier that is configured with a secure connection to your Cosmos account using one of the master keys, and all the applications (that need to be individually secured) call on to this layer for an access token. 
In this approach you will have to manage authentication of your clients to your middleware so it's definitely more involved, but ultimately more secure, especially if your APIs are deployed outside of your environment.

See [the official docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#resource-tokens) for all the details about Resource Tokens.